OpenDataCube time variable and NetCDF time variable
When try to plotting data in ODC :
My NetCDF file have 152 time variable
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (time: 152, latitude: 77, longitude: 72, depth: 8)
Coordinates:
 * depth        (depth) float32 0.494 1.541 2.646 3.819 5.078 6.441 7.93 9.573
 * latitude     (latitude) float32 9.583 9.667 9.75 9.833 ... 15.75 15.83 15.92
 * longitude    (longitude) float32 109.7 109.8 109.8 ... 115.4 115.5 115.6
 * time         (time) datetime64[ns] 2022-01-01 2022-01-02 ... 2022-06-01 
 

But when plotting to ODC
ds = dc.load(
    product="mientrung",
    x=(109.7, 115.6),  
    y=(9.583,15.92 ),  
    time=("2022-1-1","2022-6-1"),  
    output_crs="EPSG:4326", 
   
ds
xarray.Dataset
Dimensions:
time: 2 latitude: 77longitude: 72
Coordinates: 
time (time) datetime64[ns] 2022-03-17T12:00:00 2022-09-16T0...
array(['2022-03-17T12:00:00.000000000', '2022-09-16T00:00:05.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
latitude (latitude) float64 15.89 15.81 15.73 ... 9.669 9.587
longitude (longitude) float64 109.7 109.8 109.9 ... 115.5 115.6
spatial_ref () int32 4326

Why, when querying in Open Data Cube, are only two timestamps displayed?
Here is my product definition :
name: mientrung
description: GLOBAL_MULTIYEAR_PHYSIC
metadata_type: eo

metadata:
  format:
    name: NETCDF
  instrument:
    name: NA
  platform:
    code: NA
  product_type: mientrung

storage:
  crs: EPSG:4326
  resolution:
    longitude: 0.083
    latitude: -0.083

measurements:
- name: bottomT
  dtype: float32
  units: degrees
  nodata: -32767
  add_offset: 0
  scale_factor: 1
- name: mlotst
  dtype: float32
  units: m
  nodata: -32767
  add_offset: 0
  scale_factor: 1
- name: so
  dtype: float32
  units: "1"
  nodata: -32767
  add_offset: 0
  scale_factor: 0.001
- name: thetao
  dtype: float32
  units: degrees
  nodata: -32767
  add_offset: 0
  scale_factor: 1
- name: uo
  dtype: float32
  units: m s-1
  nodata: -32767
  add_offset: 0
  scale_factor: 1
- name: vo
  dtype: float32
  units: m s-1
  nodata: -32767
  add_offset: 0
  scale_factor: 1
- name: zos
  dtype: float32
  units: m
  nodata: -32767
  add_offset: 0
  scale_factor: 1

Example of metadata documents
creation_dt: '2024-09-09T14:05:10.949Z'
extent:
  center_dt: '2022-03-01T00:00:00Z'
  coord:
    ll: {lon: -180, lat: -80}
    lr: {lon: 179.9167, lat: -80}
    ul: {lon: -180, lat: 90}
    ur: {lon: 179.9167, lat: 90}
  from_dt: '2022-01-1T00:00:00Z'
  to_dt: '2022-06-01T00:00:00Z'
format: {name: NETCDF}
grid_spatial:
  projection:
    geo_ref_points:
      ll: {x: -180, y: -80}
      lr: {x: 179.9167, y: -80}
      ul: {x: -180, y: 90}
      ur: {x: 179.9167, y: 90}
    spatial_reference: EPSG:4326
id: 887af3b4-ac94-4c5d-ac25-7c3370bdd9b9
image:
  bands:
    bottomT: {path: file:///localdata/mientrung1_with_crs.nc#part=0, layer: bottomT}
    mlotst: {path: file:///localdata/mientrung1_with_crs.nc#part=0, layer: mlotst}
    so: {path: file:///localdata/mientrung1_with_crs.nc#part=0, layer: so}
    thetao: {path: file:///localdata/mientrung1_with_crs.nc#part=0, layer: thetao}
    uo: {path: file:///localdata/mientrung1_with_crs.nc#part=0, layer: uo}
    vo: {path: file:///localdata/mientrung1_with_crs.nc#part=0, layer: vo}
    zos: {path: file:///localdata/mientrung1_with_crs.nc#part=0, layer: zos}
instrument: {name: NA}
lineage:
  source_datasets: {}
product_type: mientrung
platform: {code: NA}

And data file : Here

Hi! Are you able to update your question some more detail about how you indexed your data into the datacube? E.g. product definition and an example metadata document?

I have updated this question. In the NETCDF file, there is another variable which is the depth variable, but I don't know how to add the depth variable to the product definition file. I think that could be the issue
